# Modify the signature for all users in my domain

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, service-accounts, google-workspace

Currently my code only modifies my signature, because when I put the email of the other person in my domain, the error: `Not Found (line 9, file "Code")` appears.

My current code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var newSignature = Gmail.newSendAs();
  newSignature.signature = "signature";

  var listEmails = [
    "leticia@domain.com"]

  var updateSignature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.update(newSignature, "me", listEmails)
}
```

I am developing using APPS SCRIPT.

Any suggestions for me to be able to change the signature of someone else in my domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change other people Gmail settings in your domain you'll need to be a domain Admin, then create a service account with domain-wide authority, then whitelist it in the Admin Console. Then use said service account and authentication token generated to authenticate your requests to the Gmail API.

This built-in Apps Script Gmail integration was not made for that use-case. The intended usage is to setup your own settings, or individual users that explicitly authorize your application to run on their behalf. This `sendAs` is there because one might have multiple Gmail signatures, depending on their selected send-as/from alias.

Note that simply authorizing an script with your GSuite admin account won't allow to the script to perform domain-wide operations. That'd be too dangerous, therefore the somewhat convoluted service-account setup is required.

[Link to the relevant documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings)